# How to implement a script that listens for new mail and then perform an action

Tags: perl, email, james

I have an apache James mail server setup and I would like to create a script that will listen for new mail and then communicate with an Asterisk server to call a user phone number and read the message.  I assume this is possible but cannot find any information.  I have been using perl scripting for other tasks so if I could do this with perl that would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

*A solution* would be to set up a cron job to run a perl script that uses something like `Mail::POP3Client` to check for new messages and sends something to Asterisk using (maybe) `Asterisk::AGI`.  If the CPAN modules don't do what you need, you can always have the perl script execute `system` calls to interface with command-line tools that are capable of checking POP or interfacing with Asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best way to do that is to write a [Mailet](http://james.apache.org/mailet/index.html) in java and put it in configuration to make it listen for the all mails in the root processor.

For [Apache James 3.0-beta5](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/james/james-server-app/3.0.0-beta5-SNAPSHOT/) steps would be something like this:

1. Write the Mailet i.e:

   ```
   import org.apache.mailet.*;
   public class myMailet extends GenericMailet {
     private String aParameter;
     @Override
     public void init(MailetConfig cfg) throws MessagingException {
       super.init(cfg);
       aParameter = getInitParameter("myNeatParameter"); // use this if you need to use some parameters specified inside the mailetcontainer.xml
     }

     @Override
     public void service(Mail email) throws MessagingException {
       doYourThingWith(email);
     }

     private void doYourThingWith(Mail email){
       // TODO something with the email
     }
   }
   ```
2. Build the Mailet into a jar file
3. Add the resulting jar file to /conf/lib folder
4. Edit /conf/mailetcontainer.xml file where you would add this:

   ```
   <mailet match="All" class="myMailet">
       <myNeatParameter>some value</myNeatParameter>
   </mailet>
   ```

   as a child element to the root processor (or whatever you think is proper).
5. Restart James

Well it's not a script, but it is very good (if not even the best) solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Mail::POP3Client](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mail%3a%3aPOP3Client) to poll the mailbox for messages. Or if the mailbox supports IMAP and you want to continuously monitor it, use an IMAP module, perhaps [Net::IMAP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aIMAP%3a%3aSimple) ?

I just googled for [Asterisk Perl] and [a guide called "How to Write a Perl AGI Application"](http://osnow.org/images/4/41/How_to_Write_a_Perl_AGI_Application.pdf) appeared on the first page. It describes how to use the [Asterisk::AGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Asterisk%3a%3aAGI) module to connect to an Asterisk server using Perl.

Finally, you'll need a text-to-speech application. I'm sure there are many of these available. They probably won't be written in Perl, but there may be existing Perl interfaces for them.